# Python/Pydantic iterate over post body with multiple items

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pydantic

I'm new to pydantic...I want to send (via post) multiple json entries. Is this

```
__root__
```

thingy the correct way?
How can I iterate the single entries from the post body?

```
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel  
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()


class Books(BaseModel):
    title: str
    subtitle: str
    description: str


class BooksList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[Books]


@app.post("/book_data")
def book_data(data: BooksList):
    # iterate over the single entries and insert it to my database

    return 'foo'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

And this is the postman body:

```
[
    {
    "title": "title1",
    "subtitle": "sub1",
    "description": "desc1"
    },
    {
    "title": "title2",
    "subtitle": "sub2",
    "description": "desc2" 
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate it via `data.__root__`

```
for item in data.__root__:
    do(item)
```

Or you can define own `__iter__` and `__getitem__` functions and iterate over it:

```
class BooksList(BaseModel):
    __root__: List[Books]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.__root__)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__root__[item]

#...
for item in data:
    do(item)
```

Comment: That's great. Thx